# Overriding Equals and GetHashcode and double comparison

Tags: c#-4.0, comparison, double, equals, gethashcode

I have a problem with equality and adding objects to dictionary

```
class DoublePoint
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;

    public DoublePoint(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.X = x; this.Y = y; this.Z = z;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            DoublePoint dPoint = obj as DoublePoint;
            return this.X.IsEqualTo(dPoint.X) && this.Y.IsEqualTo(dPoint.Y) && this.Z.IsEqualTo(dPoint.Z);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.X.GetCode() ^ this.Y.GetCode() ^ this.Z.GetCode();
    } 
}

static class extensions
{
    static double Tolerance = 0.001;
    public static bool IsEqualTo(this double d1, double d2)
    {
        return (d1 - d2) <= Tolerance;
    }

    public static int GetCode(this double d1)
    {
        byte[] data = BitConverter.GetBytes(d1);
        int x = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
        int y = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 4);
        return x ^ y; 
    }
}
```

and here is my test:

```
DoublePoint d1 = new DoublePoint(1.200, 2.3, 3.4);
        DoublePoint d2 = new DoublePoint(1.2001, 2.3, 3.4);
        DoublePoint d3 = new DoublePoint(1.200, 2.3, 3.4);
        bool isEqual = d1.Equals(d2); // true here


        Dictionary<DoublePoint, int> dict = new Dictionary<DoublePoint, int>();
        dict.Add(d1, 1); 
        dict.Add(d2, 2); // successful, d2 is also added but d2 is equal to d1
        dict.Add(d3, 3); // Error! since we have d1 already in dictionary
```

With this,

1. when I add doublpoint objects which are same(with some tolerance), I am able to add them in dictionary. How to restrict such objects.
2. Is the right way to compare double data types with some tolerance.

Please advice.

Thank you

Comment: Please tag the question with the language that you are developing in - you will get better answers

Comment: What language you are using??

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103782/rule-of-thumb-to-test-the-equality-of-two-doubles-in-c

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with defining "equal" as "close enough". It is no doubt useful for computations, but such "equal" violates the transitivity rule: for `Equals` if `a.Equals(b) && b.Equals(c)`, then `a.Equals(c)` **must** hold true (which is obviously not the property of your code).

So, `IsEqualTo` is unfortunately not suitable for redefining `Equals`.

What are the possible ways to solve the problem? `Equals` has to split into the disjoint groups of "equivalent" values. I usually do the following: define a rule to get the "canonical" value from a group, so two values are "equal" iff their canonical group representatives are equal.

Simple example: for just a double value `d` let's define the canonical value to be `Math.Floor(d)`. So this way you have 1.0 equals 1.1, 0.9 equals to 0.0 but *doesn't* equal to 1.0. This way is not the ideal one (after all, 0.9 being not equal to 1.0 but equal to 0.0 seems to be wrong), but at least the transitivity rule is held.

Specifically for your case it could be this way:

```
class DoublePoint
{
    public double X;
    public double Y;
    public double Z;

    const double epsilon;
    void GetCanonicalValues(out double x, out double y, out double z)
    {
        x = Math.Floor(X / epsilon) * epsilon;
        y = Math.Floor(Y / epsilon) * epsilon;
        z = Math.Floor(Z / epsilon) * epsilon;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        DoublePoint that = obj as DoublePoint;
        if (that == null)
            return false;
        double x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2;
        this.GetCanonicalValues(out x1, out x2, out z2);
        that.GetCanonicalValues(out x1, out x2, out z2);
        return (x1 == x2) && (y1 == y2) && (z1 == z2); // here we can compare
    }

    ...
```

Another problem with your code is that your `GetHashCode` is not aligned with `Equals`: if `a.Equals(b)` then `a.GetHashCode()` **must** equal `b.GetHashCode()`.

You can solve this as well by using the canonical values:

```
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        double x, y, z;
        GetCanonicalValues(out x, out y, out z);
        return x.GetHashCode() ^ y.GetHashCode() ^ z.GetCode();
    }
}
```

Beware that the behaviour of `Equals` may be unacceptable for your needs -- then you'll need to ensure the transitivity some other way.