# Multiple Update Scripts, not working with Multiple Objects

Tags: c#

Currently I have 8 objects, each with their own Update Script. What I'm trying to do, is have each object show that it is in the right location with `bools`. If it leaves the right location, the `bool` returns to `false`.

For the first two objects, the script works great. 
The first script is

`p1, with x = -2.5, and y = -2.5.`

2nd Object is

`p2, with x = 0, and y = -2.5.`

When they leave those positions, the `bool` changes to `false` without any issues.

Then when I get to the 3rd object,

`p3, with x=-2.5 and y=0`

But it shows `true` for `-2.5 x`, `-2.5 y`, when it should be `false`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void Update(){
    if(transform.position.x <= -2.5 && transform.position.y <= -2.5) {
    p1 = true;
    } else {
      p1 = false;
      }
}
```

Comment: I, err, would like to see the code for p2 and p3.

Comment: They are the exact same as the one mentioned above, except that the location changes(and bool). for p2 , p3, and so on. p2 is - transform.position.x <= 0 && transform.position.y <= -2.5. P2 works. P3 on the other hand is - transform.position.x <= -2.5 && transform.position.y <= 0. P3 Doesn't work, it shows true in the right position, but when moved down, to -2.5x it still shows true.

Comment: Well, -2.5 <= -2.5 is true. Try to use strictly inferior `<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the condition you wrote: you are testing for <= -2.5. By definition -2.5 is less or equal than -2.5 (equal in this case) therefore it will fall into the true case. if you want -2.5 be false change it to < (less than) instead of <= (less or equal).

**Update:**

From you comment I suspect the your test on p3 is for x <= -2.5 and y <= 0
If y changes from 0 to -2.5 you second condition is still true because -2.5 <= 0. If you want to test for just one correct spot you have to test for != (unequal) that number, which however might cause other problems depending on the datatype you are using. E.g. For double you might have to test Math.Abs(-2.5 - y) < 2d * `Double.Epsilon`.

For more info on that particular look [e.g. here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon.aspx) [and here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103782/rule-of-thumb-to-test-the-equality-of-two-doubles-in-c)

Comment: It won't work like that. If I change on p3 to be like that, it shows as false regardless of where its located. It needs to specifically show true at -2.5x, and 0 y. Also, if I change it to just "=" to be precise, it comes back with an error. Thank you tho :)

Comment: == is equality = is assignment.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response. I tried the method you posted, and read the links you provided (helpfull indeed). Tho it still puts me back at square one. With that method, it shows true in all of the -2.5 x locations, except for the one that is supposed to be true. It is early in the morning, maybe I'm missing something.. need more coffee mmm.

Comment: Ya, way to early in the morning for me, you are the bomb diggity Frank J .. it fixed my problem, can't believe I didn't notice something simple like that.

Comment: No problem, it is Friday after all :-)